# Python two variable for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

How to write multiple variables for loop in python. I have one variable `i` start at the beginning and `j` starting from the end. It should iterate till `i <= j.`  What's the equivalent code in python.

```
for (int i = 0,j=len-1; i <= j; i++,j--){
    // some code
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trick is using while-loop:

```
i, j = 0, len - 1
while i <= j:
    # some code
    i += 1
    j -= 1
```

Comment: Only comment is that `len` is an existing function, so using it as a variable name is not a good idea. Might be better called `length`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
for j in range(len-1,0-1):
    i=0
    while(i<=j):
        
        i+=1
```

This may work